How to get rid of caterpillars on Cassia fistula?
I'm met with an infestation of caterpillars on my Cassia fistula tree. I could see 2-3 varieties of caterpillars. The first time they came around the period when the tree was growing fiercely and getting new leaves, and ate them all up. A few weeks to perhaps a month later they've come again, right when the tree is starting to let out a lot of foliage. The tree is large enough to survive these attacks but the tree is near our house, so it's pretty uncomfortable having caterpillars raining down our driveway and crawling up to the house entrance. As mentioned, the tree being large, spray-based pesticides are not really an option. There are some natural "predators" like birds and ants around our house, but the amount of caterpillars is just too overwhelming for them to make a difference. Any suggestions to prevent the next cycle from happening is welcome.

Could you spray dish soap via your garden hose?

Photos of the caterpillars might be helpful.
